# What does equals sign g "=g" in GCC inline assembly mean / do?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm not sure what this inline assembly does:

```
asm ("mov %%esp, %0" : "=g" (esp));
```

especially the `: "=g" (esp)` part.

Comment: Not an answer by itself, but if you look at this page you can pretty well teach yourself what it all means: http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html - just search for the first `%0` on the page.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`"=g" (esp)` defines an output for the inline assembly. The `g` tells the compiler that it can use any general register, or memory, to store the result. The `(esp)` means that the result will be stored in the c variable named `esp`. `mov %%esp, %0` is the assembly command, which simply moves the stack pointer into the 0th operand (the output). Therefore, this assembly simply stores the stack pointer in the variable named `esp`.

Comment: This raises several more questions for me: 1) What does it mean for inline assembly to have an "output"? 2) can use any general register meaning eax, ebx, ecx, etc, to store the result of what? I thought inline assembly just allowed the programmer to put some 'custom' assembly in the code stream. Is this correct? if so it looks like it puts a 0 in the stack pointer register (i.e. mov esp, 0).

Comment: 2) Yes, any of the general registers. 4) GCC uses AT&T syntax, which means the first operand is the source and the second is the destination. 1,3) Inline assembly can be thought of as an inline function. It can have multiple inputs and outputs, which allow the assembly and c code to communicate with each other. The arguments are numbered for access from the code. `%0` means the 0th argument. The compiler will automatically decide what should be used and replace it in the code, and then add code to move it from there to the variable.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw: +1 for your speed, by the way :-).

Comment: man this is so weird, but I guess the point of it is if you want to assign specific registers to variables in your code? I think I finally get it now. so if I wanted the value of register eax to be stored in a variable I create, say 'x' i would write asm("mov %%eax, %0" : "=g" (x)); ?

Comment: and the actual assembly created would be something like mov %eax, x or something ? why not just put `asm("mov %%eax, x") then? why do we need this "=g" stuff? I guess what I'm asking is couldn't we figure out what assembly instructions are needed to get a register stored in a variable and use that instead?

Comment: @ladookie That's just how gcc inline assembly works. Since memory references are allowed, the compiler may do that (move the value directly to the variable). Try using `gcc -S` to see the assembly created by the compiler, and see what it actually does. You can also try different optimization levels to see what it does.

Answer (score 9):

If you want the gory details, read the GCC documentation on [Extended Asm](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

The short answer is that this moves the x86 stack pointer (%esp register) into the C variable named "esp".  The "=g" tells the compiler what sorts of operands it can substitute for the `%0` in the assembly code.  (In this case, it is a "general operand", which means pretty much any register or memory reference is allowed.)